# Total decay width of the W boson

Tags: quantum-field-theory, electroweak

I read in some particle physics book how they calculate the two body decays of the W boson, and then add all of them get the total decay width. I am wondering  about other contributions,  say, three final states decay? Can we safely neglect that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the fundamental vertices in the standard model are those of *W* coupling to a fermion-antifermion pair, (lepton-antilepton or quark-antiquark) and that's what people [have in mind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W_and_Z_bosons#W_bosons_2), to wit,

[image]

so 68% of the decay modes are hadronic.

That means that the quark antiquark pairs dress themselves up into several hadrons, which are themselves unstable, so *they*, in turn, decay to many particles. These multi particle decays are included in the 2-body primary decays.

A higher-order fundamental vertex, such as *WWγ*, where the off-shell *W* would link up to a hadron, e.g., a charged π, would be W-propagator suppressed, and, as you may see from the [PDG](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2017/tables/rpp2017-sum-gauge-higgs-bosons.pdf), it is less than one part in 100000.